# AngularJS Directive to directive communication

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I've a directive nested within another directive as in the below fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/sriramr/T7W6T/3/

My question is: if a variable in the parent directive changes value, how to automatically update the value of a variable in the child directive which is computed from the parent variable?

```
var myapp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myapp.directive('parentDir', parentDir);
    function parentDir() {
        return {
            restrict:'E',
            controller: function eCtrl($scope) {
                $scope.parVal = 100;
                $scope.$on("event",function(e,data) {
                    console.log("emit")
                    $scope.parVal = 200;
                })

            },
            template:'<div><first-dir></first-dir</div>'
        }
    }

myapp.directive('firstDir', firstDir);
function firstDir() {
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        controller: function($scope) {
            //$scope.$watch('parVal',function() {
                $scope.childVal = $scope.parVal + 1;
            //})
            $scope.changeVal = function() {
                $scope.$emit("event")
            }
        },
        template:'<div>first Dir: {{parVal}} {{childVal}} <br /> <button ng-click="changeVal()">Change</button></div>'
    }
}
```

The variable `parVal` from the parent directive's controller's scope gets handed down to the child directive's controller. The child directive has its own variable `childVal` which is `parVal + 1`. I try to change `parVal`'s value indirectly by emitting an event in the child directive. As expected, `parVal`'s value changes and is reflected in the View. However, `childVal`'s value is not changed.

I am able to see the updated value of `childVal` using a $watch on `parVal`. Is there any other way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you can share code between these two directives.

One way is to take advantage of how `firstDir` prototypically inherits from `parentDir`. You're already doing that with `parVal`, but you probably had issues updating `parVal` from within the child directive.  An easy workaround is to create an update function in the parent directive. This gives you access to update the scope directly. example: http://jsfiddle.net/T7W6T/4/
*edit:* I don't like the above approach because it tightly couples both directives and `firstDir` won't work on it's own.

Another way is to create a shared service. A service in angular is a singleton, so anywhere it is injected into a controller will be the same instance as everywhere else. You can easily create a pub/sub mechanism. Just be sure to clean up the subscribers when the scope of the subscriber is destroyed. This is my preferred way to share between directives and controllers because you don't pollute your scope.  Remember, everything bound to scope has an effect on the digest.

Example code of a minimal pub/sub mechanism:

```
myapp.service('SharedService', function(){
    var listeners = [];
    return {
        publish: function(){
            angular.forEach(listeners, function(listener){
               listener.call(null); 
            });
        },
        subscribe: function(fn){
            listeners.push(fn);
        },
        unsubscribe: function(fn){
            var idx = listeners.indexOf(fn);
            if(idx > -1){
                 listeners.splice(idx,1);   
            }
        }
    }
});
```

You interact with this from the parent directive like so:

```
            var update = function(){
                $scope.parVal = 200;
            };

            SharedService.subscribe(update);

            $scope.$on("$destroy", function(){
               SharedService.unsubscribe(update); 
            });
```

And the child directive is the only thing that can access the function to publish to listeners:

```
        $scope.updateParVal = function(){
            SharedService.publish();
        };
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T7W6T/5/

There's a pretty good explanation on SO about whether scope inheritance or `$emit` is better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18179640/151445

One thing I don't usually see mentioned about the service approach is that you control exactly where subscribers and publishers are bound. With `$scope.$emit` and `$scope.$on`, anyone with a scope can go crazy with events.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The pub-sub mechanism really helps. I updated your fiddle to include what I needed:http://jsfiddle.net/sriramr/T7W6T/7/

Isn't $emit and $watch similar to publish-subscribe? They look pretty much similar to me.

Comment: And could you tell when does the subscriber go out of scope so that the $destroy function gets called?

Comment: `$destroy` is emitted whenever the child scope is removed from the parent (via garbage collection after removal). `$emit`/`$watch` all can affect *every* scope, not just the two with the service injected.